# Using drop off folders

Tags: harmon.ie

Case: using Office 365 and Harmon.ie for Outlook 8.0.1
How do I configure the use of drop off folders? Instead of:
Having a folder structure under my inbox, from which I drag certain e-mails to the SharePoint storage

I want:
A drop off folder structure where I sort all my e-mails, and I want the e-mails copied to the SP.

BUT: I want the mails to stay in the drop off folder in the same way I would have had them in my inbox folders. I want SP to be for archive storage only, and have full access "to the left" inOutlook to my e-mails.
Now, the mails I drop in the folder are moved, not copied, to SP.

Or is there another way to automate this? BAckground reason is that company erases anything on the Outlook account/server/folder whatever, which is older than 12 months. Hence archiving on SP. But I don't want to have to judge whether a mail is worth storing, I want them all!